# Integrating cloudinary with react-native application

Tags: react-native, cloudinary

I tried integrating Cloudinary with my react native application(Android) as per the instructions given in the below link https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-cloudinary.But getting the error as in below screenshot:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ssr6.png)

Comment: Please, avoid posting pictures of code/errors if possible.

Comment: Sure. From next posts I will avoid posting picture of code/error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloudinary doesn't support React native. You might want to consider using the JS library for this matter- https://github.com/cloudinary/pkg-cloudinary-core

Comment: Is it possibe to fetch the list of images as a json stored in cloudinary with the help of package react-native fetch-blob?

Comment: You can use the 'lists' method to list all images with a specific tag. For example,

axios.get('http://res.cloudinary.com/<cloud-name>/image/list/<my_tag>.json') 
.then(res => {

console.log(res.data.ressources); 
this.setState({gallery: res.data.resources}); 

});

There is a really good tutorial that you can follow for more information on how to list your video via React- https://github.com/cloudinary-developers/build-a-mini-netflix/blob/master/React/display-videos.md